# Shell Script "cannot execute binary file"

Tags: shell, script

I'm new to putty.

However while running a shell script I got this error:

```
"cannot execute binary file"
```

I believed the syntax is :

```
sh Name_of_shellScript.sh parameters
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: run `chmod +x path/to/script/file.sh` as root and try your command again. you can probably drop the leading `sh` as well. That said though, why are you using PuTTY if you are on Linux, as it would appear, since you are trying to invoke a .sh shell script? Most linux distros have an ssh client built in.

Comment: To drop the `sh` you'll have to run it as: `./Name_of_shellScript.sh parameters`

Comment: .sh seems to indicate that it is a shell script. Cannot execute a binary file seem to indicate it is not. Can you check the contents of the file (e.g. `file Name_of_the_thing_you_tried_to_execute`) ?

Comment: Check this thread http://superuser.com/questions/435988/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-cannot-execute-binary-file whether this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a similar problem, which, at least in my case, was caused by the fact that the `.sh` file was DOS-encoded (i.e. using `\r\n` as line endings instead of plain `\n`). Converting it with the venerable `fromdos` utility of the [tofrodos package](http://www.thefreecountry.com/tofrodos/) did fix the issue.